# 'Cases' command does not recognize specified patterns

Tags: pattern-matching

I am having a problem with the "Cases" command. If I execute the following code

```
Cases[(32 W[2, 0])/5  + 32 W[2, 0]^2, W[_, _] | W[_, _]^2, {0, 2}]
Coefficient[(32 W[2, 0])/5  + 32 W[2, 0]^2, 
Cases[(32 W[2, 0])/5  + 32 W[2, 0]^2, W[_, _] | W[_, _]^2, {0, 2}]]
```

then the outputs are as expected:

```
{W[2, 0], W[2, 0]^2}
{32/5, 32}
```

However, the following similar code

```
Cases[a/(3 + c)  W[2, 0] W[2, 3], W [__, ___] W[_, __], {0, 1}]
Coefficient[a/(3 + c) W[2, 0] W[2, 3], 
Cases[ a/(3 + c) W[2, 0] W[2, 3], W [__, ___] W[_, __], {0, 1}]]
```

yield nothing in the outputs. Specifically, I got:

```
{}
{}
```

The expected outputs should be:

```
{W[2, 0] W[2, 3]}
{a/(3+c)}
```

If I get rid of the coefficient 'a/(3 + c)' then this command works

```
Cases[ W[2, 0] W[2, 3], W [__, ___] W[_, __], {0, 1}]
Coefficient[W[2, 0] W[2, 3], 
Cases[ W[2, 0] W[2, 3], W [__, ___] W[_, __], {0, 1}]]
```

and the output is as expected:

```
{W[2, 0] W[2, 3]}
{1}
```

Is there any way to get the expected output for the second code block above? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions !

Comment: I don't have an immediate solution but you can see why this doesn't work by using FullForm. The FullForm of your expression is Times[a,Power[Plus[3,c],-1],W[2,0],W[2,3]] and that of the pattern you're looking for is Times[W[Blank[],BlankSequence[]],W[BlankSequence[],BlankNullSequence[]]]. This doesn't match since the Times[...] in the expression has more arguments than in the pattern.

Comment: change it to `Cases[a/(3 + c) W[2, 0] W[2, 3], any_*W[__, ___] W[_, __], {0, 1}]` then it will work. But I do not know about your use of `Coefficient` that follows.

Comment: First, you need `HoldPattern`. But there is still a problem. Consider, if we give a list instead of an expression: `Cases[{a/(3 + c), W[2, 0] W[2, 3]}, HoldPattern[  W[_, _] W[_, _]], 1]` it works. But if we change the List to `Times`:  `Cases[Times @@ {a/(3 + c), W[2, 0] W[2, 3]}, 
 HoldPattern[  W[_, _] W[_, _]], 1]
` it does not work. Please report this to : "support@wolfram.com" and post their answer herr.

Comment: @DanielHuber I don't think this is a bug. Again, by using FullForm we can see what's going on. The FullForm of the list is List[Times[a,Power[Plus[3,c],-1]],Times[W[2,0],W[2,3]]] and that of the times expression is Times[a,Power[Plus[3,c],-1],W[2,0],W[2,3]]. Only the list-expression matches the pattern.

Comment: @banone  Hi, according to the help, `Cases`should work on list as well as expressions: see `Cases[expr,pattern,levelspec]`